# If replacing i by -i doesn't change a complex valued function, then the function output is purely real - What's proof/intuition behind this?

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider below complex function 
$$H(\omega) = \dfrac{1}{i\omega} \left(e^{i\omega} - e^{-i\omega}\right)$$

If I replace $i$ by $-i$ in $H(\omega)$, I get back the same $H(\omega)$.
Easy to see that $H(\omega) = \dfrac{2}{\omega}\sin(\omega t)$.

Long back I heard somebody claim this, but I couldn't pursue further... Now in another topic(signals and systems), this exact property is being used again.

I feel this has something to do with flip transform. Like, f(-x) flips the graph of f(x) around y axis. Since the functions see the opposite x values, so the graphs of them flip around y axis. If f(-x) = f(x), then the function is symmetrical around y axis and we call it an even function. Hmm... I couldn't connect this to the complex domain. Help appreciated..

EDIT : Here $\omega$ is a real number (angular frequency)

Comment: Do you demand the function to be analytic?

Comment: What do you mean by “purely real?”

Comment: Are you assuming $\omega$ to be real?

Comment: What "replacing $i$ by $-i$" means, is not clear. Are you assuming an explicit formula for $H(\omega)$, but then involving which functions and operations?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews sorry, by purely real i mean the function will simplify with no i's

Comment: @gimusi yes $\omega$ is a a real number (angular frequency)

Comment: @Did by "replacing i by -i" I mean,  whereever you see "i", replace it by "-i" once

Comment: Just a heads up, there's no $i$ in $\sqrt{-1}$, so replacing it by $-i$ won't help... and I know it sounds stupid (because I get what you were trying to say) but the point is that it's harder to make this claim precise than it looks...

Comment: @rsadhvika Sure, but the trouble is that "when you see $i$" is not a well defined procedure because it refers to  formula for $H(\omega)$. Surely there are different formulas for $H(\omega)$, which could give different transformed formulas.

Comment: @Did ohk.. does that ambiguity go away if we insist that $\omega$ is real ?

Comment: @rsadhvika No. I wonder if you got the point I explained...

Comment: What you are having here is that $\overline{H(z)}=H(\bar z)$ (this is the formula that involves replacing $i$ by $-i$, but of course you have to make sure that all of your operations commute with conjugation) and therefore for real $\omega$ (i.e. $\bar\omega=\omega$) you have $\overline{H(\omega)}=H(\omega)$, which means that the value is real.

Comment: @Did Yeah I feel the same, but its okay, I'll move on for now. Ty for your time :)

Comment: @CarstenS  yeah I see it only makes sense if $\omega $ is real. Looks we're on the same page..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply observe in general that

$$z=x+iy$$

$$\bar z=x-iy$$

therefore

$$z=\bar z \implies y=0$$

[image]

In your example, assuming $\omega \neq 0$ to be real and defining

$$H(\omega)=F(i\omega)$$

we have

$$F(i\omega) = \dfrac{1}{i\omega} \left(e^{i\omega} - e^{-i\omega}\right)=\overline{F(i\omega)}=F(\overline{i\omega})=F(-i\omega)$$

therefore $H(\omega)=F(i\omega)$ is real.

Comment: Hand the function in question is not always real

Comment: @dxiv yes thanks I've fixed that point!

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I'm assuming $\omega$ real.

Comment: @dxiv I'm assuming $\omega$ to be real.

Comment: @gimusi almost always, in compl x number, $\omega$ indicates a complex number. While the OP could mean it to be real, it seems highly unlikely.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I've just asked for a clarification on that point.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I just realized that H is not clearly defined.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews As you can read $\omega$ is to be assumed as a real number, that is the natural frequency.

Comment: Not sure why no notified me. Did you think I was the downvoter?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You were claiming that \omega was a complex number and that is could be highly unlike that the OP could mean it to be real. I've asked a clarification that now has been given. For that reason I notified you on that.

Comment: Oh so the function turns out to be real because $y = -y$ when $x+iy = x-iy$, Thanks I see the trick now :) Also I'd like to apologize $\omega$ is real here (angular frequency). I should have specified that in the post. Thanks again :)

Comment: @rsadhvika In your example things are a little bit complicated. Your function $H(\omega)$ can be expressed as $F(i\omega)$ which is analytic and since $F(i\omega)=\overline{F(i\omega)}=F(-i\omega)$ we have that $H(\omega)$ is real.

Comment: @gimusi $H(\omega)$ is a transfer function of a physical system. The input is just $\omega$, not $i\omega$. The input and the output of the system are real signals. Complex numbers came in because of a quadratic $1-x+x^2$ during analysis. But I kinda get how treating it as a function of iw makes sense.. Ty

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have an arbitrary complex valued function $F : A \to \mathbb{C}$ where $A$ is the domain of $F$, such that replacing $i$ by $-i$ doesn't change the value of $F$. Since every complex number can be written in the form $a+ib$ for some real numbers $a$ and $b$, for each $x \in A$ there are two real numbers $y_1, y_2$ such that
$$F(x) = y_1 + iy_2$$
but replacing $i$ by $-i$ doesn't change $F(x)$ and so it follows
$$F(x) = y_1 - iy_2$$
$$2F(x) = F(x) + F(x) = y_1 + iy_2 + y_1 - iy_2 = 2y_1$$
and so 
$$F(x) = y_1.$$

For your $H$ function I'm assuming that the domain is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ so that $\omega$ is a real number, otherwise you need to replace $\omega$ by its conjugate $\bar{\omega}$ when you replace $i$ by $-i$ (in which case the function $H$ would not be equal to it's own conjugate so it wouldn't be real valued).

Also note that I've taken a particular interpretation of what you mean by "replacing i by −i". To be specific, I interpreted it as to apply the complex conjugate map $\psi : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}, \psi(x) = \bar{x}$ to $F(x)$ so $\psi(F(x)) = F(x)$. If you meant something different my answer may not be correct.

Comment: It the above function in the question is not always real.

Comment: The domain of $H$, A, can be any set, it's not necessarily real. By "complex function", I assumed the meaning was "complex-valued function".

Comment: Still confused. Are you saying that $H(x)$ is real for any complex $x$ in the domain? Because, again, that is not true for the function in the question.

Comment: No, as written in the OP, $\omega$ must be real, otherwise $i$ was not replaced by $-i$, since $\omega$ was not replaced with $\bar{\omega}$ in the OP.

Comment: Yes for the generic $H(x)$ function I wrote in my answer $H(x)$ is real no matter what the domain $A$ is, $A$ could be the set ${a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h}$ or w/e

Comment: I'll replace the $H$ in my answer, to make it more clear.

Comment: @DAS first of all I'd like to apologize, your interpretation is correct. I see now how the imaginary component $y$ vanishes when the conjugate of a function equals the function. Thank you so much :)